# An inverse limit of a certain inverse system

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Let $∆$ be a directed set and $(N_i,f_{ji})_{i∈∆}$ be an inverse system of $R$-modules. Fix $α \in∆$ and consider $(M_i,g_{ji})_{i\in∆}$ as follows:

$M_i=N_i$  for $i≥α$,  $M_i=0$ for $i<α$, and $g_{ji}=f_{ji}$ when $j≥i≥α$, $g_{ji}=0$ when $j≥i, j<α$.

I want to prove that $(M_i,g_{ji})_{i\in∆}$ is an inverse system (which seems easy) and find $\varprojlim M_i$. Can anybody be so kind as to answer this question? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the explicit construction of the inverse limits in $R$-Mod ?

Comment: So the inverse limit would be isomorphic to the inverse limit of $N_j$ where $j$ is greater than or equal to $α$. Right?

Comment: For me is right